# How to test new Object within a function using RhinoMocks and mbunit

Tags: c#, vb.net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, mbunit

I am trying to test the below method using RhinoMocks and MbUnit however I am unable to get the test to pass. The current error is when the expect call for "" is not found.

The function is in vb.net and the test is in c#

```
 Public Function Login(user As Website.BusinessObjects.User) As Integer Implements IActivityLog.Login

        Dim item As BOAudit.IActivityLog = New BOAudit.ActivityLog(_request)

        ' Activity
        item.UserID = User.GuidID
        item.Type = Enums.ActivityType.Login
        item.Description = String.Format(If(IsAdmin, "Logged in as {0}", "Logged in"), User.FullName)
        item.EventUserID = _authenticatedUser.GuidID

        Return _dalActivityLog.Save(item)

    End Function
```

The test below is what I currently have and I believe the issue is down to declaring a new object within the function above and not passing that object into the function. What is the best way to test the above function and should I be passing in the object?

```
[Test]
    public void Login_Data_NewRecordCreated()
    {
        const int id = 99;
        var data = new Website.CodeModules.BusinessObjects.Audit.ActivityLog(_request)
        {
            Type = Enums.ActivityType.Login,
            Description = "Logged in",
            EventUserID = _user.GuidID
        };

        var user = _mocks.StrictMock<User>();

        using (_mocks.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(_dalActivityLog.Save(data)).Return(id);
        }

        using (_mocks.Playback())
        {
            var result = _balActivityLog.Login(user);

            Assert.AreEqual(id, result);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you assert in your test does not seem to have much sense. Your code seems to test that the mock instance in _dalActivityLog returns the constant that you've set up.

In that test you should test the code of the function `Login`, not the `_dalActivityLog` implementation. Thus, you should check that _dalActivityLog.Save is called with the right parameter passed.

I suppose that `_dalActivityLog` is an instance of a class that implements an interface that you haven't specified in your question. Let's call it `IActivityLog`. Then you should set up a mock instance of it in your test code.

```
IActivityLog logMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IActivityLog>();
```

Then you inject somehow this mock instance into the instance of the class the has the Login method (via constructor or property).

Then call your `Login` method and pass there an instance of `User`.

Then you make the assertion about the _dalActivityLog.Save call, like the one below.

```
logMock.AssertWasCalled(
  call => call.Save(
    Arg<Website.CodeModules.BusinessObjects.Audit.ActivityLog>.Matches(
      logItem => logItem.UserID == user.GuidID && logItem.Type == Enums.ActivityType.Login
    )
  )
);
```